# Facet and Stacked bar plot from excel to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart, facet-wrap

I want to re-produce the following figure I did on excel + MS.pptx. I am doing this because I want a most sophisticated figure. However, I am struggling a lot.

I am using ggplot2 in R but struggling with facet

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, 
             y = metric )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~scenario)
```

[image: I did this on MS excel and ppt]

[Here you can find the reproducible data.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZwkG5-XjvVBDY8dhdZJGvrH0EbiRTUCp?usp=sharing)

Any guidance to start the figure is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? What is your struggle with facet? Please describe your problem (i.e., errors/undesired result).

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(year, value, fill=fuel)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(metric~scenario, scales="free", space="fixed") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2010, 2030, 2050)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]